# VBA Remove Duplicates Row based on two Column Macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros, duplicates

I have over 200k records of customer data in my csv file.  I want to be able to create a macro that will compare Account # and product name.  Since Account # is a primay key it can only be tied to single product name.

I want my macro to give the similar output.  Right now when i run my macro on over 200k records.  I get only 20 rows.

[image]

```
Sub DelDupl()
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, Del As Integer, Msg As Integer
Set Rng = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Msg = 1 To 2
    For Del = Rng.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Msg = 1 And Application.CountIf(Rng, Cells(Del, "C")) = 1 Then

        End If
        If Msg = 2 And Application.CountIf(Rng, Cells(Del, "C")) > 1 Then
            Rows(Del).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next Del
Next Msg
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using *Data >> Remove Duplicates* ?

Comment: So you only want rows with unique account numbers left? Why not sort and then loop over that and remove an rows if equals above?

Comment: In your question you say that *Since Account # is a primay key it can only be tied to single product name.* but do you really mean *Since Account # is a primay key it can only be tied to single **customer** name.* ? If so, you should update the question because currently it doesn't scan.

Comment: If you need to check 200K rows then `Del` needs to be declared as Long instead of Integer. The maximum value for an Integer is 32,767

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN - Range.RemoveDuplicates Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx): Removes duplicate values from a range of values.

[image]

```
Sub DelDupl()

    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3, 4), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```